# SOAPACtion in Header Manager is not accepting while hitting the soap xml request

Tags: jmeter

I am getting this error message: "No Action header was found with namespace" despite providing the correct details for SOAPAction value in header. Though my same service is running in SOAPUI tool. Is there anything else I need to add in JMeter to make it run.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing the request in SoapUI and in JMeter, most probably you didn't add the [`SOAPAction` header](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528) in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

In general if you're able to successfully execute your request in SoapUI you should be able to record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare SoapUI for recording: [configure it to use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.soapui.org/docs/preferences-and-settings/#Proxy-Settings)

   [image]
2. Prepare JMeter for recording, the fastest and the easiest way is using [Recording Template](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature

   - from JMeter's main menu choose `File - Templates - Recording` and click "Create"

     [image]
   - go to HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

     [image]
3. Run your request in SoapUI
4. JMeter will capture the request and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler along with HTTP Header Manager

Comment: I am sending the SOAPAction Header but still it gives me the error. It is saying: "/s:Subcode></s:Code><s:Reason><s:Text xml:lang="en-US">No Action header was found with namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' for the given message.</s:Text></s:Reason><s:Detail><a:ProblemHeaderQName>a:Action</a:ProblemHeaderQName></s:Detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>" I took the action value from SOAPUI header running request